# Looking to ios and android scroll up and down till element found and then click

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I tried lot of blogs and discussion about ios & android scrolling in appium, java. but looks like most of method are deprecated or not working. pls helping.
I am using appium 1.15.1, java, selenium.

looking for quick help.

I am trying following code but it's scrolling twice and not even clicking.

Hi,

I am on Mac and working with real device.
I am using Appium 1.15.1, Selenium, Java with POM. 
I wrote following code for iOS swipe down.

Hi,

```
public void chkMenuOptioniOS1(String sName)
    {   
/* This is actual path which got from inspector
//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name="Account Information"]
*/
        String targetCell = "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@name,'" + sName + "')]";
        MobileElement cellWithText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(targetCell));
        HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
        scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement)cellWithText).getId());
        scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
        scrollObject.put("predicateString", "value == '" + sName + "'");
        scrollObject.put("toVisible", "true");
        driver.executeScript("mobile:scroll", scrollObject);
        try {
            System.out.println("In Try Block "+cellWithText.getText());
            Thread.sleep(10);
            cellWithText.click();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

1. It scrolling twice
2. and it;s not clicking,

Attaching DOM object screen capture.

Please help me[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the methods for your needs for iOS and Android:

```
private JavascriptExecutor js;
private HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();

void iosScrollToAnElement(IOSElement el) {
        scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
        scrollObject.put("element", el.getId());
        js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
}

void androidScrollToAnElementByText(String text) {
        try {
            ((AndroidDriver)driver).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"" + text + "\").instance(0))");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No element" + e);
        }
    }
```

after this you need to `click()` on your particular element that you are looking for. (there methods only for scrolling)

Comment: Thanks for reply bro. for iOS u r using IOSElement, I am using MobileElement and it's not working. for Android it's working perfect very first time and when I am calling same function i.e. androidScrollToAnElementByText it's keep on scrolling up and down and doing nothing. any idea about this? e.g. homePage.androidScrollToAnElementByText("Account Information") after getting account information click on that and then calling next androidScrollToAnElementByText("Log Out") for this log out it keep on scrolling up and down around few times and stop.

Comment: Apart from that if I give text which is not on page, then it keep on scrolling up and down for Android. no luck for iOS

Comment: for iOS you can use `IOSElement` ir `MobileElement` (ios element extends mobile), both of them has `getId()` methods. If it keeps scrolling, it means that there is no such element in your page. For Android, `text` is just an example. You can pass whatever you need to find your element (accessibility id, xpath or whatever). So, again, if it keeps scrolling it means that element cannot be located

Comment: For iOS: it's not scrolling. For Android yes for invalid text it;s scrolling up and down for 4 to 5 times. Is this expected? can we not keep on scrolling up and down. Thanks Bro for quick response.

Comment: have you used method for iOS as is that i pasted? There is a `Direction` cnum class that i am using, maybe you confused with this. I edited my post to use this without my enum

Comment: @Hari logic of this method is: it does one scroll iteration and try to find element, if there is no such element it keeps scrolling untill it reaches bottom of the screen. If he didn't find an element it starts the same logic but with scrolling up, and if there is no element it stops at the top os the screen.

Comment: Perfect and it's working for ios and android. One more question, I want to store option in hashmap, so there is any way I can store. Do u have code for ios and android. e.g After tapping on setting I am getting 10 option and 6 is display on screen and 4 are not but i want to store all 10 option. How do I do? e.g. https://marinetraffic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/210369227/allsettings.PNG

Comment: @Hari first: if i answered to your question - mark my answer as "best answer". For the second part: you can dynamically add options (WebElements, accessability ids or whatever you want to store) into your HashMap with `distinct` function to prevent duplicates (you can implement yoiur own logic to prevent duplicates, this is just a thought)

Comment: you better ask another question (but first perform some investigating)

Comment: @valult23 This is in regards of androidScrollToAnElementByText which you answer the question. As I said above for incorrect text search it's keep scrolling up and down for 6 times. This i am seeing every time. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFV95.png)

please try this

Comment: Please add some explanation in addition to the code snippet.

Comment: Please add some kind of guidelines or explanation.